# django & postgres linux hosting (with SSH access) recommendations

Tags: web-hosting, django

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to find web hosting that meets my requirements?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/20838/how-to-find-web-hosting-that-meets-my-requirements)

We're looking for a good place to host our custom Django app (a fork of [OSQA](http://osqa.net/)) and its postgresql backend. Requirements include:

- Linux
- Python 2.6 or (ideally) Python 2.7
- Django 1.2
- Postgres 8.4 or later
- DB backup/restore handled by the hoster, not us
- OS & dev-platform-stack patching/maintenance handled by the hoster, not us
- SSH access (so we can pull source code from GitHub, so we can install python eggs, etc.)
- ability to set up cron jobs (e.g. to send out dail email updates)
- ability to send up to 10K emails/day
- good performance (not ganged up with a zillion other sites on one CPU, not starved for RAM)
- FTP or SCP access to web logs
- dedicated public IP
- SSL support
- Costs under $1000/month for a relatively small site (<5M pageviews/month)
- Good customer service

We already have a prototype site running on [EC2](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/) on top of a [Bitnami DjangoStack](http://bitnami.org/stack/djangostack). The problem is that we have to patch the OS, patch postgres, etc.

We'd really prefer a platform-as-a-service (PaaS) offering, like Heroku offers for Rails apps, where all we need to worry about is deploying our code instead of worrying about system software patching and maintenance. Google App Engine is closest to what we're looking for, but they don't offer relational DB access (not yet at least).

Anyone have a recommendation?

Answer (score 1):

Sure of course, totally understood.  I was more comfortable going over the capabilities rather then mentioning the names however yes all of the content makes the site and i'll keep that in mind next time I respond to submissions.

My recommendations are here

Rackspace - www.rackspace.com, TX based large and easy to use, great cloud interface, no database support with basic service. vmware service available, most affordable service.

Amazon - aws.amazon.com, WA based and similar to rackspace with added database services at extra costs per service. most expensive service

Logicworks - www.logicworks.net, NY company offering infiniCloud and VMware clouds with managed database services and no contracts or activation fees.

Answer (score 1):

Just wanted to point out that BitNami now offers a cloud hosting option with on-click deployment, automated backups, ssh access, etc. http://bitnami.org/cloud

Answer (score 0):

I would consider using http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/

Comment: Yep, we already have a prototype running on EC2 using a Bitnami DjangoStack. But we were hoping to find a PaaS option which wouldn't force us to worry about patching postgres or the OS. But, so far at least, EC2 seems like a good fallback option.

Answer (score 0):

I think a web hosting user review site may be more appropriate for this, but since these questions don't seem to be going away or being closed, I will say that any VPS or managed hosting offer all of these features. And pretty much any decent web host will offer all of these features except for PostgreSQL even on shared hosting.

DreamHost, for example, provides everything in your list except for PostgreSQL in their shared hosting plan. And you can just use Amazon RDS for the PostgreSQL database.

Comment: Our app uses some postgres-specific features, so unfortunately we can't use Amazon RDS (which is mysql-based).

Comment: Also, Dreamhost is definitely high on our list of potential hosters if we can't find a PaaS option which meets our needs.

Comment: @Justin: Ah, I misread. I was looking at the Amazon EC2 database AMIs, not RDS. Which, I guess, is what you're trying to replace.

Comment: Sure of course, totally understood.  I was more comfortable going over the capabilities rather then mentioning the names however yes all of the content makes the site and i'll keep that in mind next time I respond to submissions.

Comment: Rackspace - www.rackspace.com, TX based large and easy to use, great cloud interface, no database support with basic service. vmware service available, most affordable service.

Amazon - aws.amazon.com, WA based and similar to rackspace with added database services at extra costs per service. most expensive service

Logicworks - www.logicworks.net, NY company offering infiniCloud and VMware clouds with managed database services and no contracts or activation fees.